# Creating Intent from a Class extends ListView to a Class extends Fragment

Tags: android

I'm stuck in here for almost 2days, please help:

How can I create an Intent from  'MyClass extends ListView' going to a 'Test extends Fragment'?

I used this code in MyClass:

Intent intent = new Intent(MyClass.this, Test.class);

startActivity(intent);

It doesn't work. :(

Big help! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are trying to open a view from a view which that is completely wrong.

You have Activity class for this. Put your "MyClass" in a layout xml and set content view of your  activity to that layout.(do it for both views)

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name);
```

and load view by using:

```
View v=(MyClass)findViewById(R.id.yourViewId);
```

then use intent like:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(FirstActiviy.class,SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

but before this check Android documents.